# withCredentials axios doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, axios, cross-domain

I'm developing a frontEnd using reactJs and axios to get information from an api developed in PHP Laravel.

The backEnd login part takes place in two steps:

- 1 - I send the user and password in the first route and it returns me a token; - This part is working.
- 2 - I place the token requested in step one in Berear and send a double-factor authentication code to the second route; - This part is also working

However, after being authenticated, I can't access any more private routes from my server. Then I noticed the need to set it withCredentials: true at the time I create the axios instance (This is necessary because from what I've read this setting exchanges cookies between the front and the back automatically).

So my code looked like this:

```
export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://myserver.net.br/api',
    withCredentials: true,
})
```

This configuration above works perfectly when I test my frontEnd using Firefox. But when using Chrome or Edge, it doesn't work.

I found on the forum that the problem could be because I'm running my localhost:3000 front (I don't see much sense because it works in Firefox), so I've tried using 127.0.0.1:3000 and even compiled the front and put it on the server hosting, but it still doesn't work. I can't access backEnd routes when I run front in Chrome or Edge.

Has anyone been through this situation and could you help me? I've been getting beaten for over 3 days on this! :)

Note: When I request the routes via postMan and Insominia, they also work, so it means that the CORS settings on the backEnd are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a different port for the server and the client? If so, maybe your problem is the same one that I just got.

Do your Chrome and Edge save the cookies?
If not, it is probably because the browsers force use samesite as the default.

If you are using express as the backend, maybe trying to do something like this:

```js
        return res
            .cookie("access_token", token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: true,
                sameSite: "none",
            })
            .json({your_data...});
```

I am still a newbie and just had the same problem, so if I misunderstood the problem, please explain.

Edit:
I just realise that you said you were using PHP, so if there is some option regarding adding SameSite=None to the cookies, maybe try that.